# How do I use ModalPopup from the ASP.NET Script-Only ajax control toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using the ASP.NET **Client-Side** ajax control toolkit in my asp.net MVC application. I see that there is a .js file named "AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopup.ModalPopupBehavior.js" in the AjaxControlToolkit folder. However, I cannot find any examples on how to use it.
[Edit] -
As mentioned, I am using the Client-side, Script-only control toolkit. For those unfamiliar, here is the description from CodePlex:

> AjaxControlToolkit-ScriptFilesOnly.zip
>   contains script files, CSS style
>   sheets and pictures used by the
>   toolkit. Use this download if you
>   don't want to use embedded resources
>   and prefer a file-based model.

I have not been able to find many resources on how to use some of the scripts included with this.
CodePlex link:  http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yestarday I had the same need to use the popup extender and here are the js files which you should include first.

```
<script src="javascripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="javascripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.Compat.Timer.Timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.Animation.Animations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.DropShadow.DropShadowBehavior.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.DynamicPopulate.DynamicPopulateBehavior.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxControlToolkit.PopupExtender.PopupBehavior.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The next step is to create the PopupBehavior from javascript like that:

```
$create(AjaxControlToolkit.PopupControlBehavior, {"PopupControlID":"div_to_popup","Position":3}, null, null, $get("textbox_input_id"));
```

If you need to use another control from the AjaxControlToolkit with scripts only without the burden of asp, here is one easy way to find the necessary include js files.
Go to its demo page [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx) and look at the source of the page. At the bottom you will see how to create the control. To find the include files needed for this control select CombineScriptsHandler.ashx and search for "//START". Every line with "//START" shows a script which is included in the page.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [AJAX Toolkit samples](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx). There are live demos, walkthroughs and documentation.

Comment: Sorry... as specified I am working with the Client-side only version of the toolkit, so these samples don't apply.  The client-only is all java scripts, no server controls.